# Getting the name of variable which holds an object, from the function resides in the object

Tags: javascript

Suppose an object is declared as follows

```
var object1 = {
    getName: function() {
        alert(name)
    }
};
```

Is there a way to alert `"object1"` from `getName`?

Comment: Let me just ask - **why** do you need the name of the variable? *Usually*, if you *need* the name, you're probably doing something "wrong"

Comment: You could always add a variable to the object `name: 'object1',`, but yeah, Ian asks the right question.

Comment: What should it return if `obj1 = obj2 = obj3 = { ... }`. I'd say you are approaching the problem (whatever that is) incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare an object like object literal then the answer is no, you can't get variable name. You can however declare it using constuctor:

```
function Obj() {
    this.getName = function() {
        console.log(this.constructor.name);
    }
}
new Obj().getName(); // "Obj"
```

Comment: I was heading in this direction, but this only returns the constructor name and not the name of the instance which I think is what the OP is after.

Comment: @Andy I think you are right. Will delete it, once OP make it clear what he wants.

Comment: I'd guess that the OP is attempting to mimic Java's `getName()` function (which returns the name of a class via reflection), but is confused about how "classes" are implemented in JS. I think you've given the best answer that could be given to such a question.